# Magento Can't add new product to a Category

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm new to **magento**, I'm working with the version **1.7**.

I have created a sub category "**Computers**" of the "**default category**", when I create a product and save edits it gives me :

*One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Blocks HTML output. Click here to go to Cache Management and refresh cache types.*

I assign the "**Computers**" category to the product, and it shows me that the category "**Computers**" contains a product, but when I search the product it doesn't give me anything..

Do you have any idea about this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Clear your cache and rebuild your indexes this solve your problem

Comment: Thank you :) How should I do this ? Would it solve the problem of adding product ? Regards,

Comment: Check this http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/adding-a-new-product

Comment: Also make sure that your product is in stock with some inventory

Comment: Thank you all. But I did all what you said, and it still doesn't add the product and still give me that warning, It says in the backoffice that the product has been saved, but in the front office it doesn't give me the product..

Answer (score 0):

You can pressed the button “flush cache storage" else check this link

http://magentodeveloperstips.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/one-or-more-of-cache-types-are.html

Update: Reading at http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/219407/P30/
there explain is a bug current reported.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=11406.

I found a extension **Inchoo_InvalidatedBlockCacheFix** this extension refreshes block cache after saving the product. Used to fix "One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Blocks HTML output." message.
Extension is tested only on Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

You can check source on github.

https://github.com/tomasinchoo/Inchoo_InvalidatedBlockCacheFix/tree/1.0.0

Comment: What exact Magento Version are you running ?

Comment: I'm running the 1.7 version